# SqlAlchemy - Polymorphic discriminator in a foreign table

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I'm constructing a set of tables in SqlAlchemy using `Joined Table Inheritance` with a `ParentTypes` table containing all the different types of sub-class tables as strings.

The parent table will have a one-to-many relationship with this `ParentTypes` table. What I don't know how to do (or if it is possible to do), is specify the string column in the `ParentType` table as the "discriminator" in SqlAlchemy.

Below is a simple 3-table schema, where `Child` inherits `Parent`. I'd like 'child' to be the `polymorphic_identity`. I know a workaround would be to just set the `polymorphic_on` field in the `Parent` to be just `parentTypeId`, but I'd like to avoid using these identifiers as they may change between deploys.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
metadata = MetaData()

parentTypesTable = Table(
    'ParentTypes', metadata,
    Column('parentTypeId', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String, unique=True)
)

parentsTable = Table(
    'Parents', metadata,
    Column('parentId', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('parentTypeId', Integer, ForeignKey('ParentTypes.parentTypeId'))
)

childrenTable = Table(
    'Children', metadata,
    Column('parentId', Integer, ForeignKey('Parents.parentId'), primary_key=True)
)

class ParentType(object): pass
class Parent(object): pass
class Child(Parent): pass

mapper(ParentType, parentTypesTable)
mapper(Parent, parentsTable,
    polymorphic_on= # How might I access ParentType's name column?
)
mapper(Child, childrenTable, inherits=Parent, polymorphic_identity="child")
```

Comment: The problem with that is that to my understanding SQLAlchemy tries to insert the discriminator along with other data for each entity, but the name is unique in your model. Were that not the case, you could map against a join. If you're mapping against existing tables and data, then you could load the contents of `ParentTypes` before  constructing your mappers and assign the discriminator based on that.

Comment: As an aside: star imports can be evil, such as in this case. For example `sqlalchemy.orm.join` shadows `sqlalchemy.join`. Just something that popped up while testing things.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yeah, ended up going with setting up the discriminator as just the id and determining which ids were which during initialization. And yeah, sorry about that, the star imports were just for the example - I usually do an `import sqalchemy as sa` and reference imported methods with `sa.join`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä If you want to add your suggestion of using the integer-based discriminator as an answer, I'll mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case since the tables *and* the data exist beforehand, a straightforward solution is to load the integer values that match the textual discriminators and to use those, along with

```
polymorphic_on=parentsTable.c.parentTypeId
```

Loading the values before constructing the mappers can be done using the Core `Table` definitions, after which setting the `polymorphic_identity=` arguments is a simple lookup problem.

If your schema was a bit different, you could've also tried [mapping against a join of 2 tables](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables), but since the discriminator value is inserted along with other data for each object separately, and your `ParentTypes.name` is unique, you cannot use that solution.

Comment: Would you please consider elaborating on the “Core Table definitions”? What exactly do you mean here?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting that `polymorphic_on` will work on a `Column` with a `ForeignKey` parameter only if the types table exists beforehand.

Comment: `parentTypesTable = Table(...)` etc. are "core" table definitions, and can be used to make for example queries before mapping the models in this case. You could create the mappings including `polymorphic_on` and `polymorphic_identity` definitions in advance if you know the discriminator values, but you wouldn't be able to insert new rows, if the foreign key constraint failed — and you cannot create the referencing table with the constraint, if the referenced table does not exist.